Tkinter Image Flickers When Updated
I'm currently messing around with animating Images in Tkinter and I've found that when I rapidly update an image (to create a scale animation) it flickers and looks choppy as a result. Is there a better way to animate scaling without any flickering?
Truncated code:
placeholderImg = Image.open("./assets/placeholder.png")


def actionTest():
   global img
   for i in range(20):
      resized = placeholderImg.resize((100+i*2, 100+i*2))
      img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
      canvas.create_image(480, 270, image=img)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(placeholderImg)
canvas.create_image(480, 270, image=img)

This is very similar code to a tutorial I found, but has much worse results in effect. I also found this question that was already asked but I can't seem to apply it to my code since theirs is much more abstracted and set up differently.

This does seem to be the same problem as the question you linked to.  The moment you assign the new image to img, the previous image has no more Python references to it, and immediately gets deleted.  Try assigning the new PhotoImage to a local variable instead, and only assign that to img after the image has been added to the Canvas.  (You also really need to get rid of the old Canvas items, they're just piling up in memory.)

Thank you so much! With some other edits, that worked! One last question: I'm not too educated on how tkinter works, is itemconfigure a better choice than create_image?

Yes, using .itemconfigure() to change the image of the existing Canvas item would be better that creating a new item each time.

Awesome. Python's garbage collector seems to be more aggressive in some areas than other languages I've used so this is definitely super helpful to know. Much appreciated!

According to your posted code , you should only see the last change of the image so there should not be any flickering at all.

@nezzled: Python's garbage coletor is "pretty standard" -  and won't cause surprises when compared to, say, javascript, or ruby. However, tkinter is a different beast: it actually features a TCL interpreter inside the Python runtime, and operates by different rules. That is why a reference to the PhotoImage instance is needed "on the Python side of the code", for example.

as for "not deleting the previous image" - no, tkinter runs in the same thread as your code, as does the garbage colector - it won't just update the screen (which is an expensive operation) before your code has a chance to describe the new desired state.
It is, indeed, the ".create_image" call that causes the flickering.

@jasonharper's comment was correct. Here is the updated function for other people who have this issue:
def actionTest():
   global img
   for i in range(20):
      resized = placeholderImg.resize((100+i*2, 100+i*2))
      new = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
      canvas.itemconfigure(setImg, image=new)
      img = new

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(placeholderImg)
setImg = canvas.create_image(480, 270, image=img)


There are 2 points that call attention of a reader of your snippet:

you don't perform any pause between frames when creating your images  - you just create them in  a for loop "as fast as possible". Not only tkinter, but no other animation system will look good trying to do something like this - one needs to yield sometime after a frame is updated so that the image can "settle".

The other point you are repeatedly creating new images with the .create_image call, but are not disposing of the old ones. A tkinter canvas behaves as a vector application: all created objects are "live" and "selectable" in it: so, by the end of the loop it may, at worse, try to update all 20 images created whenever the window is refreshed.


As it turns out, it is exactly creating a new image in the canvas that makes things flicker - more than the "as fast as possible" - after creating the image the first time with a .create_image call, its "PhotoImage"  content must be updated with a call to canvas.itemconfig, and not subsequent create_images
So, each frame update should: update the canvas image, not recreate a new item on the canvas, and schedule the next frame redraw after a few milliseconds, and pass control back to tkinter, so that it can "do its business" (handle mouseclicks, key presses, actually redraw the screen and such)
In the tkinter model the way to do that is having a function which will be called at some point to draw a frame, and return after doing that - and for a simple animation, the frame drawing function can schedlue itself as a callback with a tkinter.after call.
Unfortunately your snippet is not a "complete, minimal example", in which it is missing the imports, creation of the root window, etc: pleas when asking questions do paste code that can run, without modifications, so that we only have to answer your question. Instead, I now have to create the boiler plate that you already have around there, and that is not much fun.
So, as you can see, the function drawing the frame needs to know some state from one being called once to the next.  (Your "i" variable used in the for) - we could use a global variable as you do to preserve a reference to the PhotoImage instance. However, this is exactly a good case to use a class, with a method that will render the frames, and have the instance to hold the wanted attributes of scale and such.
SO, it turns out I made a class to draw the image and perform an animation, but unlike the answer you linked, it does not inherit from tkinter components: you just instantiate it from your code, as you'd call your function, and call the .reset  method on it, I made it separate so that a simple button can make the animation be replayed.
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class ScaleAnim:
    def __init__(self, canvas, base_img, target=20):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.base_img = base_img
        self.target = target
        self.canvas_img = None
        self.last_frame_id = None
        self.callback_id = None

    def reset(self):
        if self.callback_id is not None:
            self.canvas.after_cancel(self.callback_id)
        self.step = 0
        self.canvas.after_idle(self.draw_frame)

    def draw_frame(self):
        # for  a "real world"  case, consider caching these re-scaled objects in a dictionary
        # instead of performing a PIL-resize on each frame:
        # PIL uses the CPU for that and it is resource intensive
        new_img = self.base_img.resize((100 + self.step * 2, 100 + self.step * 2))
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_img)
        if self.canvas_img is None:
            self.canvas_img = self.canvas.create_image(256, 256, image=self.img)
        else:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_img, image=self.img)
        self.step += 1
        if self.step < self.target:
            self.callback_id = self.canvas.after(30, self.draw_frame)  # schedule next frame 30 miliseconds ahead.
        else:
            self.callback_id = None

    def __del__(self):
        # Not really needed in this minimal example,
        # but these two lines can make the image "vanish itself"
        # from the canvas when the instance is discarded:
        if self.canvas_img is not None:
            self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_img)


def main():

    base_img = Image.open("placeholder.png")
    print(base_img, base_img.size)

    win = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width=512, height=512)
    canvas.pack()
    scale_anim = ScaleAnim(canvas, base_img)
    button = tk.Button(win, text="animate", command=scale_anim.reset)
    button.pack()
    win.after_idle(scale_anim.reset)
    win.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

